Smoothness of Curve on Surface with Self-Intersection $-1$
Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface over any alg closed base field $k$ of arbitrary characteristic. Let $C \subset S$ be an reduced, irreducible Gorenstein curve with self-intersection $-1$, ie $C^2=-1$.
Must be this curve neccessarily be isomorphic to $\Bbb P^1$? Eg, cannot it be eg singular?
By adjunction formula we have $2g_C-2=deg(K_C)=K_S.C+C^2=K_S.C-1$. By Gorenstein $K_C$ is invertible. Can it be from $C^2=-1$ valone bededuced that $C$ must be smooth?

@Mummytheturkey: Could you maybe sketch the idea how to see it  in case $S$ non rational, resp an counterexample for rational $S$?

@Mummytheturkey: You mean van der Geer's book also with title "Hilbert modular surfaces"?

Take any smooth surface $X$ with a singular reduced irreducible curve $C$ with $C^2=r\geq 0$. Blow up $X$ at $r+1$ smooth points of $C$ to get a smooth surface $Y$ and the proper transform of $C$ which is singular and has self- intersection $ -1$. Your hypothesis on Gorenstein is unnecessary. Any reduced irreducible curve on a smooth surface is locally Gorenstein.
